# Изменение DOM из модуля JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, dom, nwjs

Пишу приложение на nwjs.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть главный файл `main.js` - подключен к html-документу. Из этого файла идет вызов функции, которая находится в модуле `barScript.js`.

В этой функции мне необходимо изменить содержимое тега в html документе

```
document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "..."
```

В консоли появляется `"...Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at..."`

При попытке изменить стили то же самое.

Есть ли возможность влиять на DOM из модуля? В интернете про это ничего не нашел

---

Воссоздал участок кода в отдельных файлах

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title></title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src='main.js' defer></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="but" onclick="add()">Нажать</div> 
<div id="par"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

main.js

```
function add(){ 
  var mod = require('./barScript'); console.log(mod()); 
}
```

barScript.js

```
var array_counter = function(){ 
  document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = 'Hello'; 
}; 

module.exports = array_counter;
```

Та же ошибка

Comment: Очевидно, DOM-элемента с id information не существует на странице

Comment: Воссоздал участок кода в отдельных файлах

//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='main.js' defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="but" onclick="add()">Нажать</div>
    <div id="par"></div>
  </body>
</html>

//main.js
function add(){
  var mod = require('./barScript');
  console.log(mod());
}

//barScript.js
var array_counter = function(){
  document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = 'Hello';
};
module.exports = array_counter;

Та же ошибка

Comment: Извиняюсь за форматирование

Comment: В приведенном коде нет места с *чтением* свойства `innerHTML`. Попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: @Igor извините, где нет? Возможно я неправильно выразился- есть главный файл js, а из главного файла идут вызовы различных функций из модулей. И мне нужно из модуля как-либо повлиять на DOM

Comment: Сейчас я в ответе покажу.

Comment: @Igor И изменение innerHTML происходит как раз в модуле, т.е. в файле barScript.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Чтобы изменить DOM из модуля необходимо (Для nwjs):

1. В главном JS файле вызвать функцию модуля и передать в нее
   элемент DOM, который необходимо изменить.
2. В модуле сделать все изменения.
3. Вернуть измененный элемент DOM.

Вот пример (Берем текст, который вводит пользователь и, нажав кнопку, вставляем его в div):

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" name="" value="Push">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <div id="text"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```js
const module = require('./module');

var but = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    inpText = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1],
    blockText = document.getElementById('text');

but.addEventListener("click", function() {
  module.showMessage(inpText, blockText)
});
```

module.js

```js
module.exports.showMessage = (inpText, blockText) => {

  blockText.innerHTML = inpText.value;
  return blockText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы привели текст ошибки

> "...Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at..."

и код, который, как Вы считаете, к этой ошибке приводит

```
document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "...";
```

---

Этот код не может вызывать эту ошибку:

```js
document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "...";
```

А этот - может:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("information").innerHTML;
```

Так какой у Вас код?

Comment: Код такой, как я привел выше.

Именно присваивание
'document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = "Hello";'

А ошибка эта:
_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at array_counter (C:\Users\danil\Desktop\nwjs-sdk-v0.36.0-win-x64\site\barScript.js:2:44)
    at add (chrome-extension://jdcffhnndajlmpkjhjeoalgiifijllgb/site/main.js:3:15)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (chrome-extension://jdcffhnndajlmpkjhjeoalgiifijllgb/site/index.html:9:35)_

Comment: @СергейДанилюк Вы не видите, что теперь ошибка не такая, как в вопросе? "Минус сейчас поставлю Вам." (с)

Comment: Извините. Я экспериментировал. Один код был скопирован при попытке считать, а другой при попытке изменить. Суть одна- из модуля не получается повлиять на элемент DOM. А из файла, который подключен к html- получается. Сейчас попытался из модуля вернуть в главный скрипт элемент впринципи, а в главном скрипте вывести возвращенный элемент в консоль. Вывелся null